# How to load xml code block into existing xml file at a specific node using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have an xml template (ReportTemplate.xml) with the following:

```
<Report xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner" xmlns:cl="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/componentdefinition" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/reportdefinition">
  <ReportSections>
    <ReportSection>
      <Body>
        <ReportItems>
          <Tablix Name="Tablix1">
            <TablixBody>
              <TablixColumns>

              </TablixColumns>
              <TablixRows>

              </TablixRows>
            </TablixBody>
          </Tablix>
        </ReportItems>
      </Body>
    </ReportSection>
  </ReportSections>
</Report>
```

I have created xml snippets (tablixrow.xml) not fully qualified xml documents as such

```
<TablixRow>
  <Height>0.26736in</Height>
</TablixRow>
```

In my console app I am trying load both files and insert tablixrow code block into the TablixRows node of the parent document

```
 private static XDocument GenerateReport(List<string>fieldnames)
        {           
            //load base template
            XDocument report = XDocument.Load("Templates/ReportTemplate.xml");
            XNamespace ns = report.Root.Name.Namespace;
            //load row template
            XDocument tRows = XDocument.Load("Templates/tablixrow.xml");
             //and here is where I am stuck


            return report;
        }
```

I'm new to linq and I am trying understand how to navigate to the "TablixRows" node and then insert the tRows block of code.

Can anyone provide some points of reference or examples. What I have see thus far always navigated to and ID. I cannot use id's in this schema and need to rely on the node

-cheers

Comment: You will have problem with namespaces here, thus you are trying to add existing xml without declared namespace to xml with default namespace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private static XDocument GenerateReport(List<string>fieldnames)
{
    XDocument report = XDocument.Load("Templates/ReportTemplate.xml");
    XNamespace ns = report.Root.Name.Namespace;
    XElement row = XElement.Load("Templates/tablixrow.xml");

    // change namespace for loaded xml elements
    foreach (var element in row.DescendantsAndSelf())
        element.Name = ns + element.Name.LocalName;

    var rows = xdoc.Descendants(ns + "TablixRows").Single();
    rows.Add(row);

    return report;
}
```

If you will not change namespace for row template xml, then after adding to report document it will have default namespace (which you don't want):

```
<TablixRows>
  <TablixRow xmlns="">
    <Height>0.26736in</Height>
  </TablixRow>
</TablixRows>
```

If some of your templates will have attributes, then you need to provide namespace for attributes also.